# Accented characters in LaTeX subscript in math mode

Tags: vertical-alignment, accents, subscripts

When using an accented capital letter in a subscript, LaTeX lowers the subscript box:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$A_\textup{foo}$ $A_\textup{Cech}$ $A_\textup{Čech}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Subscripts not vertically aligned]

The first two subscripts are vertically aligned, while the last one is lowered because it contains a Č as part of a proper name. In my opinion, this is undesirable if both subscripts appear on the same line.

I know that I can lower the non-accented subscript boxes by using

```
A_\text{\vphantom{Č}foo}
```

However, this stretches out the line too much, and it means a lot of work and ugly code to add a \vphantom to all the subscripts.

Rather, I would like to tell LaTeX to put the Čech-subscript box on the same height as the other ones. Since I'm using a macro for `\textup{Čech}` anyway, I'm hoping to replace it by something which does the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\smash`:

```
\documentclass[border = 5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$A_\textup{foo}$ $A_\textup{Cech}$ $A_\textup{\smash{Čech}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: better to smash the whole word, so you don't lose inter-letter kerning

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I didn't know kerning is lost in smashing. I've just tested, and indeed, for this pair, the difference is 0.1 pt, but I can imagine that it will be more for other pairs.

Comment: the `\smash` alone works here, but i'd be tempted to add a `\vphantom{C}` for insurance.  (i tend toward overkill.)